# Is it safe to invoke unordered_map::operator[] while reading a member of the map?

Tags: c++, concurrency, std

I know that I may not access `operator[]` on an `std::unordered_map` concurrently from multiple threads.

However, suppose I surround the `operator[]` invocation itself with a mutex, while accessing the elements themselves is still concurrent:

Am I allowed to read/write to an element of the map through a pointer, at the same time that a different thread is calling `operator[]`?

For example:

```
    // This code will run concurrently from multiple threads

    Thing* thing = nullptr;
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(my_mutex);
        thing = &my_map[thread_id];
    }

    // This may happen at the same time operator[] is called
    thing->value += 10;
```

Is this safe?

Or, for example: may `operator[]` move stuff in memory, thus invalidating the `Thing*` pointer being held by a different thread at the moment?

Comment: Any other thread could do `my_map.erase(thread_id)` in between the mutex being released and the statement `thing->value += 10;` thus invalidating the pointer `thing` .

Comment: In general you can always access a data structure (or resource) from several separate threads of execution as long as what you do to the data structure or content does not "screw up" the view of reality that the others have.  My favourite metaphor is a public rest room. Each visitor must get access to each toilet, sink, towel dispenser one at a time and leave it usable for the next visitor. Identify the public and private areas of your data structure and put locks on the "doors" you identify :). E.g., you need to lock only write-access usage of operator[]. Good luck!

Comment: @Kjell-OlovHögdahl Sure, I guess the question here is: may operator[] suddenly move stuff in memory, thus invalidating the `Thing*` pointer being held by a different thread at the moment?

Comment: @G.M. Sure, I'm wondering if this is safe assuming nobody erases the element I'm currently using. Please see the updated 1. bullet in my question.

Comment: @G.M. Once again simplified the question.

Answer (score 0):

From [`std::unordered_map/operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at), emphasis mine:

> If an insertion occurs and results in a rehashing of the container, all iterators are invalidated. Otherwise iterators are not affected. **References are not invalidated**.

So your are fine.